# In each of the following, $f$ is assumed to be continuous. Pick out the cases when $f $cannot be onto.

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

**[NBHM_2007_PhD Screening Test_Topology]**

> In each of the following, $f$ is assumed to be continuous. Pick out
>   the cases when $f$ cannot be onto.
>
> 1. $f:[-1,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$
> 2. $f:[-1,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{Q} \cap [-1,1]$
> 3. $ f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow [-1,1] $

I could judge the (2.) since the cardinality of c0-domain less than domain. so, $f:[-1,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{Q} \cap [-1,1]$ can be on to. Am I right?. For (1.) and (3.) I am helpless. I know $[-1,1]$ is compact, whereas $\mathbb R$ is not compact. Can I judge using this knowledge?. Continuity is in our hand. Please help me.

Comment: Connectedness and compactness are preserved by continuous functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Image of compact(Connected) set is compact (connected) under continuous map. For $3$ think $\mathbb R$ as $(-1,1)$ then try to construct a continuous onto map.

Comment: then 2. must be false no?

Comment: Yes $1$ and $2$ are answers of your question. Btw, your cardinality argument is not valid.

Comment: Answer is given (1) and (2) in the key.

Comment: what about 3. one?

Comment: I also told you $1$ and $2$.

Comment: why on to function is possible?

Comment: I already gave you the hint for third one.

Comment: since, cardinality of $(-1,1)$ and $\mathbb {R}$ same. so there exists an on to function possible. Am I right?

Comment: How to to use compactness? I don't know. continuity is also not counted in my argument.

Comment: Recall that $(-1,1)$ and $\mathbb R$ are homeomorphic. So its enough to construct a continuous onto function from $(-1,1)$ onto $[0,1]$

Comment: I meant $[-1,1]$ instead of $[0,1]$

Comment: @Dontknowanything; How do you know that it is possible to find a continuous function from $(-1,1)$ to $[-1,1].$

Comment: @Dontknowanything; I agree that a bijective function always exists but how do you know it is continuous and I think the OP requested that too from you

Comment: Dear @Maths_Is_Fun: Its not hard to construct required continuous function. Its easier to construct such function by drawing the graph and then you can write down the function explicitly. If you're unable to find after trying lemme know,i'd be happy to help you!

Comment: @Learnmore Consider $f : \Bbb{R} \to [-1,1]$ given by
$$f(x) = \begin{cases} -1, &\text{ if } x \le -1\\
x, &\text{ if }x \in [-1,1]\\
1, &\text{ if } x \ge 1\end{cases}.$$
Then $f$ is continuous and onto.